# Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3} $ such that: ...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A \begin{bmatrix}1&1&a\\2&1&b\\3&1&c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&2\\1&1&3\end{bmatrix}$ 

and let $Y=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

Then $AX=Y$ has infinite solutions for all $a,b,c$.

Why is this correct? I can't seem to understand how I am supposed to reach that conclusion (it was a multiple choice question and this was the correct answer). 
Any help or explanation is appreciated.

Comment: In your question, the letter $b$ stands for two distinct things.

Answer (score 5):

Since $A \begin{bmatrix}1&1&a\\2&1&b\\3&1&c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&2\\1&1&3\end{bmatrix}$, you can easily see that :

- $A \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$
- and $A \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

So for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, $A (\lambda \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix} + (1-\lambda) \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

So there are infinite solutions, and this does not depend on the values of $a,b,c$.

Comment: What is the point of $\lambda\in[0,1]$? I think the proof is true for any $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, (though it doesn't affect the solution) I am just asking.

Comment: Yes it's true. I edited (it's juste because I often use convex sets so ...)